# How do I wrap multiple elements in a flexbox container with a border that doesn't extend to the full width of the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm new to this. I'm trying to make a flexbox container for multiple elements with a border that doesn't span the full width of the page and instead wraps around the elements regardless of their 'flex-basis' value.  Here's the code:

```css
body {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 1.2rem;
      }

      .table {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        border: 5px solid rgb(75, 100, 182);
      }

      .table > * {
        flex-basis: 100px;
      }

      .bronze {
        background-color: rgb(116, 97, 44);
      }
      .silver {
        background-color: silver;
      }
      .gold {
        background-color: gold;
      } 
      .platinum {
        background-color: rgb(69, 179, 173);
      }
      .diamond {
        background-color: rgb(175, 81, 175);
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="bronze">Bronze</div>
      <div class="silver">Silver</div>
      <div class="gold">Gold</div>
      <div class="platinum">Platinum</div>
      <div class="diamond">Diamond</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

I want to be able to change the 'flex-basis' value of all the items in the container and still have the border wrap around all the elements and not extend to the full width of the page.

If I change the `display: flex;` to `display: inline-flex` and then use `width` instead of `flex-basis` then it works but I don't want to use `width`, just `flex-basis`. I don't want to change the `flex-direction` of the container. I've tried changing the display to `inline-flex` and not use `width` but doing that results in the `flex-basis` getting completely ignored. I'm learning so my knowledge is limited but I tried everything I know and nothing works. I'm stumped.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use width to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to adjust the `flex-basis` property of `flex` items within a container, while keeping the borders around the items intact and preventing them from extending to the full width of the page. You mentioned that changing the display property to inline-flex and using width instead of flex-basis works for your layout, but you prefer to use flex-basis.

To achieve this, you can set the `flex-basis` property of the `flex` items, but you also need to make sure that the sum of `flex-basis`, `flex-grow`, and flex-shrink does not exceed the available space within the `flex` container. If it exceeds the available space, the items will no longer fit within the container, and the borders will extend to the full width of the page.

Here is what you need to do:

```
 <body>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="bronze">Bronze</div>
      <div class="silver">Silver</div>
      <div class="gold">Gold</div>
      <div class="platinum">Platinum</div>
      <div class="diamond">Diamond</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

```
   body {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        font-size: 1.2rem;
      }

      .table {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        border: 5px solid rgb(75, 100, 182);
      }

    
    

      .table > * {
        flex-basis: 100px; /* Adjust the flex-basis as needed */
  flex-grow: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
     border: 1px solid red; /* these are the borders from the items */
      }

      .bronze {
        background-color: rgb(116, 97, 44);
      }
      .silver {
        background-color: silver;
      }
      .gold {
        background-color: gold;
      } 
      .platinum {
        background-color: rgb(69, 179, 173);
      }
      .diamond {
        background-color: rgb(175, 81, 175);
      }
```

I hope this works, if you have any further questions you can ask me!

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried what you suggested and the result was pretty much the same. The border still extends to the full width of the page and leaves a huge blank space between the last element and the right side of the border which extends all the way to the right side of the page.

Comment: Hello! You there? Please help me with this one!